# ActionScript 3 collision

Tags: flash, actionscript, collision

I am working on a flash game, using actionscript 3. Its just like a maze game. We have a boat and ropes creating the path. I am getting a collision issue. While getting the boat through the path its colliding to the ropes properly in X axis & Y axis, and its working fine but when it collides on any corner (where X & Y axis meets), it just crosses over the rope.
Here is my collision script.

```
if (leftArrow)
{
    boat.x -=  speed;
    if( rope.hitTestPoint(boat.x,boat.y,true) ){
                boat.x += 5;
            }
            if( rope.hitTestPoint(boat.x,boat.y+height,true) ){
                boat.x += 5;
            }

}
else if (rightArrow)
{
    boat.x +=  speed;
    if( rope.hitTestPoint(boat.x+boat.width,boat.y,true) ){
                boat.x -= 5;
            }
            if( rope.hitTestPoint(boat.x+boat.width,boat.y+height,true) ){
                boat.x -= 5;
            }

}
else if (upArrow)
{
    boat.y -=  speed;
    if( rope.hitTestPoint(boat.x,boat.y,true) ){
                boat.y += 5;
            }
            if( rope.hitTestPoint(boat.x+boat.width,boat.y,true) ){
                boat.y += 5;
            }

}
else if (downArrow)
{
    boat.y +=  speed;
    if( rope.hitTestPoint(boat.x,boat.y+boat.height,true) ){
                boat.y -= 5;
            }
            if(rope.hitTestPoint(boat.x+boat.width,boat.y+boat.height,true) ){
                boat.y -= 5;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hitTestPoint is good for finding if a point is in an object, but it falls short when using it for game-like situations because you have alot of points to check if you are dealing with varying shapes and degrees of movement. The solution is in hitTestObject. It works similar to hitTestPoint, except you are comparing a display object instead of a single point. There is one issue though: you are comparing bounding boxes. The trick is to create a box with alpha 0 over your object's graphics (in your case the boat) that covers as much as possible and won't cause collisions that don't make sense to the player, you call it something like 'hit', and then run collision detection against that. There is a good explanation here: http://bit.ly/Oj2ZCe

One note: so in their example, that point of the ship is pretty far out of the invisible 'hit' box. What you can do to improve it a little further is combine it with the hitTestPoint function and run an extra collision detection on any odd pointy parts like they have.

That's the gist of it. This would reduce your code to something like this:

```
var rememberX:Number = boat.x;
var rememberY:Number = boat.y;

if (leftArrow)
{
    boat.x -=  speed;
}
else if (rightArrow)
{
    boat.x +=  speed;
}
else if (upArrow)
{
    boat.y -=  speed;
}
else if (downArrow)
{
    boat.y +=  speed;
}

if(rope.hitTestObject(boat.hit))
{
    boat.x = rememberX;
    boat.y = rememberY;
}
```